# Clearing the session variables when user leaves the page

Tags: javascript, spring, jsf, session, primefaces

I want to clear the session variables when the user leaves the page.
I have a form in which i am displaying a datatable based on the selected values from h:selectOneMenu.
The form has a  cancel button which calls the destroy method that is used to clear the session variables.
It all works fine.

Problem Description:
I am calling a javascript function which gets called under onunload event.
This function clicks a hidden button 'destroyBtn'. The button in turn calls the destroy() method.
The destroy method gets called and the values are cleared but the page navigation stops 
when the i click on any link outside the form or the back button. I am using @Component and @Scope("session").

```
function destroy(){
alert("Inside Destroy");
document.getElementById('MainForm:destroyBtn').click();
}


<h:commandButton id="destroyBtn" styleClass="none" value="Destroy" ajax="false"
 actionListener="#{TutorialsBean.destroy}" />




public void destroy(){
this.searchTxt="";
this.accessType.clear();
this.roleCart.clear();
this.manager = null;
this.helpList.clear();
this.setComment("");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.Is there any other way session can be handled using JSF and Spring.

Comment: Your button doesn't seem calling `destroy()` method. What is `handleDestroy()` method. Is it a typing mistake?

Comment: That's a typing mistake prageeth...

Answer (score 0):

why not keep the scope as view? Your data is saved only till the user is on the page and cleared when user leaves the page.

Comment: Thanks Pavan, i know that would help.but isn't there any way to clear the variables by keeping the scope as session?

Comment: I tried using View Scope. For this i had to port jsf's view scope to Spring using custom scope feature.Now the variables get cleared when i leave the page.The only problem is that i am using a button which opens a new dialog using which the user can select a value which gets added to the list. Now , opening the dialog creates a new view and i am unable to retain values on the parent page.